# How to enforce that one date is bigger than the other in angular reactive form?

Tags: angular, validation, angular-validation, angular-validator

I've the following reactive form:

```
  newTripForm = this.formBuilder.group({
    name: new FormControl('', Validators.compose([Validators.required, Validators.minLength(3)])),
    startDate: new FormControl('', Validators.required),
    endDate: new FormControl(''),
  });
```

How can I add a validator enforcing that the endDate is bigger than the startDate? Also, is there a way to check that the startDate and endDate are dates? I didn't found any validator?

Thank you very much(and sorry for the noob question)

Comment: Write custom validator for date. And instead of using text input for Date, use library. See [this](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-datetimepicker) example

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If your control is a normal date input this will do the job and you can format the values if your controls are a custom types like ngBootstrap date picker "like in my case"

```js
export class DateValidators {
  static greaterThan(startControl: AbstractControl): ValidatorFn {
    return (endControl: AbstractControl): ValidationErrors | null => {
      const startDate: Date = startControl.value;
      const endDate: Date = endControl.value;
      if (!startDate || !endDate) {
        return null;
      }
      if (startDate >= endDate) {
        return { greaterThan: true };
      }
      return null;
    };
  }
}
```

usage

```js
const startControl = this.formBuilder.control('');
const endControl = this.formBuilder.control('', [DateValidators.greaterThan(startControl)]);
```

Answer (score 2):

The validators you have used so far are `FormControl`-validators. They validate a single `FormControl`. You can also write yourself a validator that validates a `FormArray` or a `FormGroup`.
A validator would look something like this:

```
dateOrderValidator(formGroup: FormGroup): ValidationErrors | null {
  const startDate = formGroup.controls['startDate']?.value;
  const endDate = formGroup.controls['endDate']?.value;
  // validate date-strings
  // catch missing values
  if (Date.parse(startDate).getTime() >= Date.parse(endDate).getTime)) {
    // return an appropriate error
  }
}
```

#### FormBuilder

FormBuilder's main purpose is to save us some boilerplate. Instead of
`name: new FormControl(...)`
we can just write

```
name: ['initialValue', [<synchronous validators>], [<asynchronous validators]]
```

or even less (if we have no validators):

```
name: 'initialValue'
```

Comment: Although "validate date-strings" should be the responsibility of the field validators, not the form group validator.

Comment: Correct. What I meant was: do not use `Date.parse().getTime()` without ensuring that you can parse the given string.